# Vertical Align With Scroll Over Effect

Tags: html, css

I want to vertically align my text (which is more than one line) while using the scroll-over effect. I tried putting `vertical-align: middle;` into my code, but it just wouldn't work.

My CSS code

```
.splash-container {
    background: #ffffff;
    z-index: 1;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    position: fixed;
    top: 100px; left: 0; bottom: 0; right: 0;
    /*margin-top: 20%;*/
}

.splash {
    width: 80%;
    height: 50%;
    margin: auto;
    text-align: center;
}

.splash-head {
    font-size: 20px;
    font-weight: 900;
    font-family: "Lucida Sans", Helvetica, sans-serif;
    color: #333;
    border: 3px solid #333;
    padding: 1em 1.6em;
    border-radius: 5px;
    line-height: 1em;
}

.splash-subhead {
    font-family: "Lucida Sans", Helvetica, sans-serif;
    color: #333;
    letter-spacing: 0.05em;
    opacity: 0.8;
}

.content-wrapper {
    position: absolute;
    top: 100%;
    z-index: 2;
    background: #f2f2f2;
}
#description {
  padding: 50px;
}
```

Here is the HTML:

```
  <div class="splash-container">
      <div class="splash">
          <h1 class="splash-head">Title</h1>
          <p class="splash-subhead">
              Text
          </p>
          <p><a href="..." >Button</a></p>
      </div>
  </div>

<div class="content-wrapper">
  <div class="content">
      <div id="description">(Text that will scroll over)</div><hr>
    </div>
</div>
```

I want splash-container to have a vertical-align, so that all of the text in it is in the middle of the screen. I tried doing this with `vertical-align: middle`, but it didn't work.

Any ideas? Thank you.

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit? Your question is not very clear. What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I want to vertically align all of the text in the splash-container div (I.e. The title, the text and button) in the middle of the screen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is it something like this you are looking for?

```css
html, body { margin: 0; height: 100%; }

.splash-container {
  background: #ffffff;
  z-index: 1;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0; left: 0; bottom: 0; right: 0;
  display: table;
  /*margin-top: 20%;*/
}

.splash {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
  text-align: center;  
}

.splash-head {
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: 900;
  font-family: "Lucida Sans", Helvetica, sans-serif;
  color: #333;
  border: 3px solid #333;
  padding: 1em 1.6em;
  border-radius: 5px;
  line-height: 1em;
}

.splash-subhead {
  font-family: "Lucida Sans", Helvetica, sans-serif;
  color: #333;
  letter-spacing: 0.05em;
  opacity: 0.8;
}

.content-wrapper {
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 2;
  background: #f2f2f2;
}
#description {
  padding: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="splash-container">
  <div class="splash">
    <h1 class="splash-head">Title</h1>
    <p class="splash-subhead">
      Text
    </p>
    <p><a href="..." >Button</a></p>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="content-wrapper">
  <div class="content">
    <div id="description">(Text that will scroll over)</div><hr>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Edit: LGSon posted a much more elegant looking solution!**

https://jsfiddle.net/0xt6r1s7/

I'm not sure what the scrolling div should do, but this will vertically/horizontally center the `.splash` using pseudo elements for the `vertical-align: middle;`

Added a horrible grey border so it's clearer where the `.splash` element is.

```css
.splash-container {
    background: #ffffff;
    z-index: 1;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0; left: 0; bottom: 0; right: 0;
    text-align:center;
}
.splash-container:before {
  content:"";
  width:1px;
  display:inline-block;
  height:100%;
  vertical-align:middle;
}

.splash {
  border:1px solid #ddd; /* Demo purposes, as button has some space underneath it which makes it look out of alignment */
    width: 80%;
    margin: auto;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align:middle;
    display:inline-block;
}

.splash-head {
    font-size: 20px;
    font-weight: 900;
    font-family: "Lucida Sans", Helvetica, sans-serif;
    color: #333;
    border: 3px solid #333;
    padding: 1em 1.6em;
    border-radius: 5px;
    line-height: 1em;
}

.splash-subhead {
    font-family: "Lucida Sans", Helvetica, sans-serif;
    color: #333;
    letter-spacing: 0.05em;
    opacity: 0.8;
}

.content-wrapper {
    position: absolute;
    top: 100%;
    z-index: 2;
    background: #f2f2f2;
}
#description {
  padding: 50px;
}
```

```html
 <div class="splash-container">
      <div class="splash">
          <h1 class="splash-head">Title</h1>
          <p class="splash-subhead">
              Text
          </p>
          <p><a href="..." >Button</a></p>
      </div>
  </div>

<div class="content-wrapper">
  <div class="content">
      <div id="description">(Text that will scroll over)</div><hr>
    </div>
</div>
```